# Calculating shear amplitude for molecular dynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, viscosity, molecular-dynamics, rheology

I’m working on a molecular dynamics simulator and want to find shear amplitude. How could do I so when particles are moving randomly? The simulation is 3d, I know some stuff about shear anplitude. I know if (in 2d) shear wave is in x direction then we only consider shear amplitude in y direction. I also know when plotting it should be sinossoidal. I just can’t calculate it.

Any help would be great